# Apply bootstrap tooltips based on name

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am using Bootstrap tooltips as follows:

```
<a class="tip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip text"> <!--Some Element --> </a>

$(".tip").tooltip;
```

I have some standard text fields that I am using which appear on my page based on some conditions using PHP.

How can I apply a tooltip based on name along with a default text without using an anchor tag?

So I want to do this using jquery. Use a name selector to select any field with the name "Name" and apply the tooltip "Here is the name" so that it would match the field irrespective of the condition being satisfied.

Or should I do this some other way?

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to use the bootstrap tooltip for input elements, here is one method of doing so.

**Live example on JS Bin**
http://jsbin.com/eGErEWo/1/edit

**JS snippet**

```
  $("input[name='fooName']").tooltip({
      "title": "Yo! Here is an input.", 
      "trigger": "hover", 
      "placement": "top" 
   });
```

**HTML snippet**
All that is pertinent here is the name of the input, `fooName`.

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password" name="fooName">
```